# How requeue messages in rabbitMQ to emulate sleep()? right way

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm taking message from queue, processing it and for some messages at some point I understand that I have to wait for several seconds before trying to process it.

Options are:

- I can call sleep() and wait, but sometimes there could hundrends of messages, and luanching that many workers is not an option.
- I can simply requeue message, but is it a good idea? I will be processing it again and again with the same result. (Processing includes DB queuring, etc)
- I can send myself a new message, including timestamp to know if it's time to process a message or not. So on arriaval I'm just going to check timestamp and if it's good procceed to usual processing.

Obviously, third way it better, but should I send this messages to the same exchange/queues, or is it a good idea to create different exchange "processing_pass2"? Or may be there are some built-in functionality @rabbitMQ to perform such a task? Requeue message to appear again after given number of seconds?

Comment: hey there, did you got it?